# Typically how many remapped sectors are allotted per GB by HD vendors?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

Some general questions about how much space is used and allotted for replacing bad sectors in modern hard disks:

1. Typically how many [remapped sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector) are allotted per GB by hard disk vendors?

   This average should include, if possible, both P-LIST (**P***ermanent* remapping during factory production tests) and G-LIST (**G***rowth* remapping by disk microcode during consumer usage) allotment.
2. Does [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis,_and_Reporting_Technology) tend to have some sector/GB ratio that it regards as unacceptable?

Comment: Probably difficult to find out, as you can get at the "remapped sectors after production" list only with vendor-specific tools, none of which are public.

Comment: "Typical" results aren't going to be much use - the number will vary wildly according to the disk technology (expected fail rate) and the intended use ("premium" server devices tend to reserve much more than "consumer" or "budget" ones).

Comment: @TobySpeight, re *"might vary wildly"*: plausible, perhaps true, but without figures, it's hard to say what's typical and what's wild variance.  If wild variance exists however, I'd be interested in typical numbers within the various grades of drives: "consumer", "enterprise", etc.

Comment: I don't have any figures, but some reviews of SSDs do note the difference between claimed capacity and the memory ICs found inside.  That's harder to do for spinning metal oxide, though.